# missing dependency for remi while updating php 5.1 to 5.3

Tags: php, yum

I want to update php-5.1 to php-5.3 using remi, but I am facing a missing dependency problem.

I have given the command, "yum update php"

It is giving the following error.

> php-cli-5.3.6-3.el5.remi.x86_64 from remi has depsolving problems
>   --> Missing Dependency: libedit.so.0()(64bit) is needed by package php-cli-5.3.6-3.el5.remi.x86_64 (remi) php-gd-5.3.6-3.el5.remi.x86_64
>   from remi has depsolving problems   --> Missing Dependency:
>   libt1.so.5()(64bit) is needed by package
>   php-gd-5.3.6-3.el5.remi.x86_64 (remi) Error: Missing Dependency:
>   libt1.so.5()(64bit) is needed by package
>   php-gd-5.3.6-3.el5.remi.x86_64 (remi) Error: Missing Dependency:
>   libedit.so.0()(64bit) is needed by package
>   php-cli-5.3.6-3.el5.remi.x86_64 (remi)  You could try using
>   --skip-broken to work around the problem  You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
>                           package-cleanup --dupes
>                           rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

I am using "CentOS release 5.4 (Final)"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one

It's using different sources, but it works for me

http://www.question-defense.com/2009/07/15/upgrade-php-version-51-to-php-version-52-with-yum-on-a-centos-server-running-ispconfig